# How to change the animator controller state name?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, I'd like to change the three newly created states in the animator controller.  How can I change the names?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a box where you can simply edit the name. It appears in the inspector window, once you selected a state.

If you didn't change your layout too much, it should be on the top right:

[image]

When you edit it, be sure to press enter. Clicking outside of the box will cancel the change